# Correct way to interpret conditional probability wording

Tags: conditional-probability, bayesian

I would like to double check my interpretation of a probability question.

2% of a population have a given medical condition.
There is a medical test for that condition with 90% accuracy.

If a person tests positive, what is the probability the person actually has the condition?

Based on this, I have determined that the question is looking for P(D|pos)

Let pos = positive test result

Let D = condition of having the medical condition

- P(D) = 0.02
- P(pos|D) = 0.9
- P(pos|Dc) = 0.1

Question:

1. Does my interpretation look correct?
2. Have I found all the correct ingredients?

Comment: @tommik I deleted my earlier comment as I saw the same Wikipedia page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_and_specificity) actually defining "accuracy" - but definitely *not* as "Sensitivity and/or specificity when they are the same" but as "rate of the result being correct" (counting both true positives and true negatives as "correct"). So we need to get back to OP and ask what they call "accuracy" in their book.

Comment: @StinkingBishop : sorry but to solve the exercise you have to know both Sensitivity and Specificity, that is sure!

Comment: @tommik Yes. Silly me.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Assuming that, with the term "90% Accuracy", we mean that Both Sensitivity and Specificity are 90%,

Yes, your interpretation is correct. Using your ingredients and Conditional probability's definition you get

$$\mathbb{P}[D|\text{pos}]=\frac{0.02\times0.90}{0.02\times0.90+0.98\times0.1}\approx15.52\%$$

Comment: Thanks. I 100% agree. the question does not detail those. I spent ages thinking about sensitivity and specificity and came to the same conclusion they must be equal. Thank you.